# "mettre en valeur que" + phrase?

Tags: expressions, usage

On peut utiliser l'expression *mettre en valeur* avec un nom.

> Cette peinture met en valeur les difficultés de la vie auparavant.

Est-ce qu'on peut l'utiliser aussi avec une phrase ?

> Je voudrais mettre en valeur que sans votre aide, l'organisation de cet événement n'aurait pas été possible.

Comment: Ça dépend du contexte je pense. Tu analyses une lettre ou tu fais un discours de remerciement ? Le choix de mots est assez différent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comme souvent avec les expressions qui s'emploient avec un nom, on peut remplacer ce nom par « le fait que » suivi de la proposition. L'exemple devient :

> Je voudrais mettre en valeur **le fait que** sans votre aide, l'organisation de cet événement n'aurait pas été possible.

Certains reprochent à cette tournure d'être un peu lourde, mais elle a l'avantage de fonctionner à tous les coups.

Answer (score 1):

Cela me semble juste mais je trouve qu'une phrase comme "Je voudrais mettre en valeur votre aide, sans vous l'organisation de cet événement n'aurait pas été possible." me parait plus correcte.

Comment: Proposition intéressante, mais j'aurais mis un deux-points à la place de la virgule, pour montrer qu'il s'agit d'une explication.